# How do I shred just the first and last part of a device?

Tags: linux, shred

The `shred` command (of `coreutils` 8.23) overwrites a device with configurable data from beginning to end which is perfectly fine for the use cases it is designed for (which are all related to write something to the complete device).

In my case it”d be sufficient to do with the x first bytes and y last bytes of a device what `shred` does to the whole device, but I don't seem to find a good solution avoiding to specify explicit value (device size, etc.). I could write from a random source to a calculated part of the device with `dd`, but then I have to get the device size, struggle with MiB and MB, etc. Maybe there's something as comfortable as `shred` (or I'm just missing something).

Mostly partitioning related information (gpt, msdos partition table and backups) are placed at the beginning and end of a device.

Comment: I had to read this three times to understand your problem. Am I correct in assuming your question is basically: **How do I shred just the first and last part of a device?**. Though I wonder why you would want to shred just that part.

Comment: @Nifle Going through old questions. You're absolutely right, no idea why I chose this title and insisted on it after your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure what you really want isn't "**`wipefs`** - *wipe a filesystem signature from a device*"?

---

`dd` isn't that difficult to use, especially getting the right numbers from `gparted` or `fdisk`, see below.

The whole-disk method works, as in `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx`. Possibly with `bs=1M` to increase the speed. Or replace `/dev/zero` with /dev/urandom` for more random-looking data. As in "[ArchWiki's Securely wipe disk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Securely_wipe_disk)".

For just one partition number "n", aka "sdxn", could do `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdxn`

For just the "first" n MB's, you could do `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=1M count=n`

For the "start" & "end", you could find out the drive's sector size & total sectors - `gparted` tells you that easily, under "View -> Device Info", and it even tells you where a partition's start & end sectors are. `parted` & `fdisk` (for MBR) should too.

Then, use some math to figure out where to wipe.

- Tiny (512b) exact way - find which sectors to wipe. If your drive has 512 byte sectors, and has 251658240 sectors (is 120GB,=  251658240 sectors * 512 bytes / 1024 convert to k / 1024 to M / 1024 to G)...

  - to wipe the last 1G (gig, G=1024*1024*1024 bytes) you could figure the sectors in 1GB (1GB/512b = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 512 = **2097152**), then subtract that from the total sectors 251658240 - 2097152 = **249561088** and start at that sector for that many sectors:
    `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 seek=249561088 count=2097152`
- You could convert the `bs`, `seek` & `count` to use M (M=1024*1024) instead, if it's too slow going 512b at a time. The disk always starts at 0, but ends on 251658240 * 512 / 1024 / 1024 = **122880** in M's.

  - Wipe the last 1G There's 1024 M's in a G, so skip over 122880 - 1024 = **121856** M's and do:
    `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=1M seek=121856 count=1024`
- Gig-at-a-time rough estiamte, works fine where writing beyond the "end" causes no damage (the very end of the disk, not wiping a middle partition). Try 1G (G=1024*1024*1024 bytes) at a time. See `man dd` for more info, it understands K, M, G, others.

  - The last G, `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=1G seek=119` omitting `count` to keep going right to the end of the device.

---

Or, for a probably **faster** way to write "random" data to a whole partition/drive, you can use [**dm-crypt**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Drive_preparation#Secure_erasure_of_the_hard_disk_drive):

> First, create a temporary encrypted container on the partition (sdXY)
>   or the full disk (sdX) you want to encrypt, e.g. using default
>   parameters
>
> ```
> # cryptsetup open --type plain /dev/sdXY container
> ```
>
> Second, check it exists
>
> ```
> # fdisk -l
> Disk /dev/mapper/container: 1000 MB, 1000277504 bytes
> ...
> Disk /dev/mapper/container does not contain a valid partition table
> ```
>
> Finally, wipe it with pseudorandom (encrypted data), a use of
>   /dev/urandom is not required as the encryption cipher is used for
>   randomness:
>
> ```
> # dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/container
> dd: writing to ‘/dev/mapper/container’: No space left on device
> ```